# Promise to change background color gone wrong

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am learning promises in JS, I have tried somethings accidentally, but then I ended up with doubts. I have mentioned what I expected from code in `//comments`. The actual change on web page was - after 1 sec `backgroundColor` gets red but there is no change in color afterwards!!

```js
    const colorChange = (newColor) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(newColor); // returns resolved promise without any delay
        })
    }
    
    colorChange("red")
        .then((newColor) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('in 1st then ', newColor);
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
                return colorChange("yellow"); // I think this will return a resolved promise after (1 sec from start)
            }, 1000);
        })
        .then((newColor) => { // I think after (1 sec from start) this will get executed
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('in 2nd then ', newColor); // I thought that this should be yellow, but it is undefined!! why?
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor; // I think this will get executed after (2 sec from start)
            },1000);
        })
```

Console

```
in 1st then  red
in 2nd then  undefined
```

Can someone explain how this code ran?

Comment: Oh, is it like in the first "then" it returns resolved promise with value as "undefined". And the second then also gets triggered as soon as code ran and not after 1 sec?? Please explain in detail how thinks work!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise` and `setTimeout` are asynchronous, returning something inside their callback will not affect outer function's return as it's execution is already completed.

You can try like this if you want, resolving promise based on timer.

```js
const colorChange = (newColor, resolveAfter) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (resolveAfter) {
          setTimeout(() => resolve(newColor), resolveAfter);
      } else {
        resolve(newColor); // returns resolved promise without any delay
      }
    })
}

colorChange("red")
.then((newColor) => {
      console.log('in 1st then ', newColor);
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
       //this will return a resolved promise after (1 sec from start)
    return colorChange("yellow", 1000);
})
.then((newColor) => { // after 1 sec from start this will get executed
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
})
```

Comment: understood, and I think your code changes backround color from red to yellow in 2 seconds (1 sec promise + 1 sec setTimeout)

Comment: yes that's correct, you can remove `setTimeout`  in second then, updated snippets.

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve("red"), 1000); // (*)

}).then(function(result) { // (**)


  console.log('in 1st then ', result);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = result;
  result = "yellow"
  return result ;

}).then(function(result) { // (***)

    console.log('in 2second then ', result);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = result;
    result= "blue"
    return result ;

}).then(function(result) {

    console.log('in 3th then ', result);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = result;
    result= "red"
    return result ;

});
```

Comment: you should return promise and not result(color), in your code basically all then runs at once and the last change is what you see, the color blue.